# how to override flywaydb V4.2.0 oracle system schema clean changes

Tags: flyway

Among the changes in flywaydb V4.2.0 is enforcement of disabling of the clean function for [oracle system schemas](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/1559).  This is a sensible move, but is causing issues for us because we have numerous schemas that have been created, perhaps naively, in the root container in oracle 12c.  This means that we have many schemas that are considered by flyway to be oracle system schemas, though they are in fact user created, which it refuses to clean.

The most technically correct solution would be to create these schemas in a PDB rather than the root container, but due to the work required to migrate to a PDB with the large number of schemas that we have it may well not be an option that the business is willing to consider, certainly not in a big-bang way that affects all schemas at once.

Ideally we would like to be able to override or modify the behaviour of flyway when working with these schemas to allow clean during development and testing.  Is there an existing solution that would permit this, either by setting a flyway execution option or by changing metadata in the target database?  This will allow us to migrate at an appropriate pace to properly configured PDB containers and still upgrade to V4.2.0 or later flyway versions.  Without a solution to this we are stuck with flyway V4.1.2 until we have migrated all schemas that we work with.

Comment: Feel free to comment in the issue tracker if you feel the new restrictions are too strict and want to propose an alternative

Comment: Thanks Axel, I have commented on the issue in the tracker.  I do think that because the impact of this is going to prevent upgrade to V4.2.0 while using oracle 12c in some circumstances there should be the option to set a switch that downgrades behaviour to the old, pre V4.2.0 definition of system schemas.